# How to find source code of specific version of linux tools, i.e. ifconfig

Tags: linux, version-control, ifconfig, source-code

I had a weird situation yesterday when a shell script broke on the machine of colleague. the Script was parsing output from `ifconfig`, and it would assume that there was no `:` (colon) after the interface name.

E.g. directly behind the `eth0`:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:da:bb:a9
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:feda:bba9/64 Scope:Link
```

I have confirmed already that the output is different between Distributions, e.g. on CentOS it looks quite different.
I was wondering about a good way to version-track code like this.
Given a specific Linux distro/version, how can I quickly get to the source code of its `ifconfig` program?
How would I know, when it has changed the last time, or how often it changes?

Comment: Don't parse `ifconfig` - it's meant for human consumption.  Use something like `ip link` instead.

Answer (score 4):

On many distros `ifconfig` is deprecated and replaced by the `ip` command.  On my Centos7.4 `ifconfig --version` says `net-tools 2.10-alpha` while on my Ubuntu 16.04 it says `net-tools 1.60 / ifconfig 1.42 (2001-04-13)`.

You can usually get the source for a package by installing `{package}-src` or some such with the distro's package manager.